# Why is my low pass filter attenuating everything so much?

Tags: capacitor, audio, filter, active-filter

I have a car stereo with low level outputs from an RCA connector. I wired one channel into a simple RC LPF, then into a TPA3116-based amplifier ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HZKM2QC)), then to a single 4 ohm woofer. [image: circuit diagram]

Using a 100u or 47u capacitor (shown in picture), I can't hear anything at all, just static if I put my ear right up to the woofer. If I put in a 10u cap, I can faintly hear low notes and high notes, but I don't think the high frequencies are being filtered out, and it's ridiculously quiet everywhere. If I'm not mistaken, with R=8 and C=10u, I should notice frequencies above 2kHz being significantly quieter. If I remove the capacitor altogether, the woofer is significantly louder, so I know the amplifier is working properly. What gives?

Comment: I think we'll need a proper schematic rather than a stand-in schematic. The TPA3116 is a bridge-mode amplifier (and not an op-amp as marked in your partial schematic) so the speaker is not supposed to be connected to ground. As you have shown it there will be a DC bias of Vcc/2 on the speaker. Please mark the chip pins on the schematic.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to include a link to the off-the-shelf amplifier I'm using. I don't have the actual schematic, but some of the traces are visible in the images on the listing.

Comment: You've provided a link to an Amazon ad page instead of a datasheet with circuit diagram.   "*No datasheet? No sale!*" There's a reason it looks like a bargain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter pulls your signal source on its knees. Try about 100x bigger R1 and drop the capacitance of C1 to about 0,5uF.

To be exact the output impedance of your signal source and the input impedance of your amp should both be taken into the account. Unfortunately I do not know them.

BTW 1st degree RC-lowpass filter has poor frequency selectivity. The attenuation increases as the frequency increases but there's no clearly noticeable steep frequency limit. 2nd order filter would be much more selective.

Comment: Since I was using low-level outputs, the 8 ohms was indeed killing my source. Upped it to R=5k and C=68n and the problem was mostly fixed.